# Adding shadow to UICollectionViewCell slows down scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionviewcell

I am able to successfully add shadow to UICollectionViewCell by adding the following code to 
cellForItemAtIndexPath method

```
cell.image.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
cell.image.moviePlayerView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
cell.image.moviePlayerView.self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 5);
cell.image.moviePlayerView.self.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
cell.image.moviePlayerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
```

but it makes the scrolling really slow. I understand its adding shadow to the cell when its scrolling but can not figure out the solution. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution and hope this would be helpful to others. Instead of adding shadow separately, now I am merging existing image with shadow image and using the result image.

```
UIImage* image = [image imageWithFileShadow];

- (UIImage *)imageWithFileShadow {
static CGFloat pointScale = -1.0f;
if (pointScale < 0.0f) {
    pointScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
}

CGFloat imageWidth = (int)self.size.width;
CGFloat imageHeight = (int)self.size.height;

UIImage * shadowImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"FileShadowResizable"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0f, 24.0f, 29.0f, 24.0f)];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, pointScale);
[shadowImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, imageWidth, imageHeight) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0f];
[self drawInRect:CGRectMake(14.0f, 8.0f, self.size.width - 28.0f, self.size.height - 29.0f)];

UIImage * mergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return mergedImage;
}
```